# Magento products show up in all categories

Tags: magento, categories, product

I have a problem with products on my category-pages.
I've got 2 sub-categories, both with products. When I call the category-page of the first category, products from both categories show up.

When i turn the theme back to the default magento theme, only the products from the correct category show up.
I have already looked in the list.phtml file, but that's not it.

Got any idea's where to look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For me the problem was in the 2columns-left.phtml file of my theme.
I compared it to the base 2columns-left.phtml file and saw some differences. Then is was easy to see which one it was and to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is a local.xml in your theme folder. The local.xml is used to apply specific changes without affecting the fallback system. Check the loca.xml for any specific changes to <"catalog_category_default"> , <"catalog_category_layered"> or <"default">.

If there is no local.xml in your theme folder you should check the catalog.xml.

You could open the catalog.xml from the default folder and open it next to the one you use in your theme. Then step by step check the differences.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, Thanks! it helpt a lot finding my answer.